# How to get parent address for child in sql query (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

Given the two tables parent and child like this:

```
PARENT
id (pk)
address

CHILD
id (pk)
address
parent (fk)

Ex:
PARENT
id      address
1        West street
2        East street
3        South street

CHILD
id      address         parentid 
1        1st street      3
2        2nd street      (null)
3        (null)          2
4        4th Street      1

Expected outcome for child id in(1, 3)
childid address
1        1st Street
3        East Street
```

I am looking for a query that lists the children's ids and addresses for a predefined set of children (ex. id IN (1, 4, 5, 8, 9)). If a child's address is null, then I want to display that child's parent's address instead.
How to write a query (for Oracle db) that gives me the desired outcome?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Sample data and desired outputs please (formatted text not images).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated sub-query and coalesce:

```
SELECT id,
       COALESCE(
         address,
         ( SELECT p.address FROM parent p WHERE c.parent = p.id )
       ) AS address
FROM   children c
WHERE  id IN (1, 4, 5, 8, 9);
```

or you can use a join:

```
SELECT c.id,
       COALESCE( c.address, p.address ) AS address
FROM   children c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN parent p
       ON ( c.parent = p.id )
WHERE  c.id IN (1, 4, 5, 8, 9);
```

*(Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in case you do not have information on the parent.)*

Comment: Thank you - I really liked to see two different ways. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need a case:

```
select case when c.address is null then p.address else c.address end as address
from child c
     join parent p on c.parent = p.id
where c.id in (1, 4, 5, 8, 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I got you you need children´s id (in a set), if they are someone null, you want to show father´s id... Try this:

```
select coalesce(a.address,b.address) from children a 
inner join parent b on a.parent = b.id where a.id in (1,4,5,8,9)
```

**Coalesce** returns first non null expression in the list. So, you will return children id, if not you will return parent id (respective coming from inner join cross).

**Inner Join** cross two tables and returns rows what matches with specification.

Comment: Thank you. I just updated my questions with a sample to better communicate what I was looking for. It is the address field that may be null, and not the id-field.

Comment: Welcome. It is the same, just change the fields what you want to return... I edited my answer. @user3249152

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was helpful!